# Need to Replace the Object key name to another name and Pass down to dropdown list using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to  Replace the Object Key name  "Value" to "label" and Pass down to DropdownList..
For Example, I am Using "item.value" in the Dropdown Component, But now I need to get the Inputs Data and replace "item.value" to "item.label"...
So How Can I change that Object Key name and render the List in DropDown
Can Anyone help in this, Thanks in Advance

```
export const inputs = {
    "purpose": [
         {
            "locale": "er",
             "code": "zzz",
             "value": "Payment"
         },
         {
            "locale": "po",
             "code": "dgf",
             "value": "Support"
         },
         {
            "locale": "fg",
             "code": "oiuy",
             "value": "yes Worked"
         },
```

Here is the Dropdown

```
const Dropdown = () => {
    const data = inputs;
    //console.log(data.purpose);
    return (
                <select >
                    <option>Select an Option</option>
                    {data.purpose.map((items)=>(
                           //console.log(items.value);
                           <option>{items.value}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dropdown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a copy of the array with new keys by mapping through it as:

```
const transformed = inputs.purpose.map(({ locale, code , value }) => ({ label: value, locale: locale, code : code}));
```

Answer (score 1):

easy way :

```
const new=inputs.purpose.map(i=>{
    const temp={};
    temp.locale=i.locale;
    temp.code=i.code;
    temp.label=i.value;
    return temp;
    })
```